# How to change color in Python?

Tags: python, colors, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def move():
    global x1, y1, dx, dy, flag, n

    x1, y1 = x1 + dx, y1 + dy

    if x1 > 360:
        n = 0
        x1, dx, dy = 360, 0, 15

    if y1 > 360:
        n = 1
        y1, dx, dy = 360, -15, 0

    if x1 < 10:
        x1, dx, dy = 10, 0, -15
        n = 2

    if y1 < 10:
        y1, dx, dy = 10, 15, 0
        n = 3

    can1.coords(oval1, x1, y1, x1 + 30, y1 + 30)

    if flag > 0:
        abl1.after(50, move)

def stop():
    global flag
    flag = 0

def start():
    global flag
    if flag == 0:
        flag = 1
        move()

###

x1, y1 = 10, 10
dx, dy = 15, 0
color = [["white"], ["red"], ["green"], ["blue"]]
n = 0

flag = 0

###

abl1 = Tk()
abl1.title("Animációs gyakorlat Tkinter-rel")

can1 = Canvas(abl1, bg = "dark grey", height = 400, width = 400)
can1.pack(side=LEFT)

oval1 = can1.create_oval(x1, y1, x1 + 30, y1 + 30, fill = color[n])

but1 = Button(abl1, text = "Quit", command = abl1.destroy).pack(side=BOTTOM)
but2 = Button(abl1, text = "Start", command = start).pack()
but3 = Button(abl1, text = "Stop", command = stop).pack()

abl1.mainloop()
```

When the ball reaches the edge of the square, it has to change color. Now with this list of colors and with ifs it doesn't do anything and I don't know what's wrong. I tried a lot of different variants but did not work either.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your move function you have to set the itemconfig() fill parameter on each iteration.  The call to can1.create_oval() returns an ID for the oval which you can pass into the itemconfig() method as the first argument.  You can then set the fill from there as in the code below.  This is not the most efficient way to code this though.  With all your globals it may be best to make this script into a class.

```
def move():
    global x1, y1, dx, dy, flag, n

    x1, y1 = x1 + dx, y1 + dy

    if x1 > 360:
        n = 1 
        x1, dx, dy = 360, 0, 15
        can1.itemconfig(1, fill=color[n])

    if y1 > 360:
        n = n + 2
        y1, dx, dy = 360, -15, 0
        can1.itemconfig(1, fill=color[n])

    if x1 < 10:
        n = 2
        x1, dx, dy = 10, 0, -15
        can1.itemconfig(1, fill=color[n])

    if y1 < 10:
        n = 3
        y1, dx, dy = 10, 15, 0
        can1.itemconfig(1, fill=color[n])

    can1.coords(oval1, x1, y1, x1 + 30, y1 + 30)

    if flag > 0:
        abl1.after(50, move)
```

Comment: @req Technically a mix of both of our answers is correct because mine is still being called on every iteration where the given conditional is true. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Inside of your `x1 > 360` check in `move()`, `n == 1` should be `n = 1`.

I assume `n` is the variable you're using as your list index. If so, you need to add the following line before your `flag > 0` check at the bottom of `move()`:

```
can1.itemconfig(oval1, fill=color[n])
```

That should change the colours like you wanted.

Copy-paste of my version of your `move()`:

```
def move():
    global x1, y1, dx, dy, flag, n

    x1, y1 = x1 + dx, y1 + dy

    if x1 > 360:
        n = 1
        x1, dx, dy = 360, 0, 15

    if y1 > 360:
        n += 2
        y1, dx, dy = 360, -15, 0

    if x1 < 10:
        x1, dx, dy = 10, 0, -15
        n = 2

    if y1 < 10:
        y1, dx, dy = 10, 15, 0
        n = 3

    can1.coords(oval1, x1, y1, x1 + 30, y1 + 30)

    can1.itemconfig(oval1, fill=color[n])

    if flag > 0:
        abl1.after(50, move)
```

Edit: Jaredp37's answer would definitely be more efficient than mine, since mine tries to change the colour every time the function gets called.